# UnhandledException not called when exception thrown in another thread

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0, clr

According to the Microsoft documentation, when an unhandled exception occurs on a thread (from either the thread pool or created using the System.Threading.Thread class) the AppDomain.UnhandledException event should fire for the default AppDomain of the application. Here is the MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) which explains it after the second NOTE section.

But I cannot reproduce this behaviour, as far as I can tell from my test application it never fires the UnhandledException on either the default AppDomain or the AppDomain used to create the thread. Is the documentation wrong or my testing code?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Program.HookAppDomainExceptions();
        Test t = CreateTestInsideAppDomain("Nested1");
        t.SetupNested1();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Test CreateTestInsideAppDomain(string appDomainName)
    {
        AppDomain nested1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain(appDomainName);
        string executingName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        return (Test)nested1.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(executingName, "Test");
    }

    public static void HookAppDomainExceptions()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException +=
            new EventHandler<FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs>(FirstChanceException);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
            new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }

    public static void FirstChanceException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Domain:{0} FirstChanceException Handler",
                          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }

    public static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Domain:{0} UnhandledException Handler",
                          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
}

public class Test : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private delegate void Nothing();

    public void SetupNested1()
    {
        var start = new Nothing(Nested1ThreadStart);
        start.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }

    static void Nested1ThreadStart()
    {
        Program.HookAppDomainExceptions();
        Test t = Program.CreateTestInsideAppDomain("Nested2");
        t.SetupNested2();
    }

    public void SetupNested2()
    {
        Program.HookAppDomainExceptions();
        Test t = Program.CreateTestInsideAppDomain("Nested3");
        t.ThrowException();
    }

    public void ThrowException()
    {
        Program.HookAppDomainExceptions();
        throw new ApplicationException("Raise Exception");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your code `UnhandledException` isn't fired on any `AppDomain`, because if you call a delegate using `BeginInvoke()`, any exception that is thrown during its execution is handled and then rethrown when you call `EndInvoke()`, which you don't.

If you either call `EndInvoke()`:

```
start.EndInvoke(start.BeginInvoke(null, null));
```

or execute the delegate synchronously:

```
start();
```

You get similar results: `UnhandledException` of the main domain is raised.

If instead, you do what the documentation says and start a new thread using the `Thread` class:

```
new Thread(Nested1ThreadStart).Start();
```

`UnhandledException` of `Nested1` and the main app domain are raised.

So, to answer your question: The documentation is right. Your code is wrong. When you call delegate asynchronously using `BeginInvoke()`, you should always call `EndInvoke()` later.

Comment: I would rather go for `start.BeginInvoke(iar => start.EndInvoke(iar), null)` because your usage makes the method call syncronous. Otherwise, excellent answer!

Comment: @Jonathan, yeah, that works too, but it changes the behavior. It calls `EndInvoke()` on the thread used to call `start`, which means is raises `UnhandledException` on `Nested1` (and the main domain).

Comment: @svick - There is no point to EndInvoke(BeginInvoke) unless creating a sync version of a method that is naturally async.

Comment: @Jonathan, in actual application, there isn't. But this is not actual application, it's just code used to figure out how `UnhandledException` behaves.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem too. I used **Observer Pattern** to solve that.
you can implement an interface in your caller class that have a method which call from the other thread when an exception occurs.

Here's a link that shows how to implement this pattern [Exploring the Observer Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx)

Comment: That's not what this question is about. The OP (probably) knows how to handle exceptions if he wanted (or was able) to do it. The question is what happens to *unhandled* exceptions.